# Multiprocessing AsyncResult.get() hangs in Python 3.7.2 but not in 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, virtualenv, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to port some code from Python 3.6 to Python 3.7 on Windows 10.  I see the multiprocessing code hang when calling `.get()` on the `AsyncResult` object.  The code in question is much more complicated, but I've boiled it down to something similar to the following program.

```py
import multiprocessing


def main(num_jobs):
    num_processes = max(multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1, 1)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_processes)

    func_args = []
    results = []

    try:
        for num in range(num_jobs):
            args = (1, 2, 3)
            func_args.append(args)
            results.append(pool.apply_async(print, args))

        for result, args in zip(results, func_args):
            print('waiting on', args)
            result.get()
    finally:
        pool.terminate()
        pool.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(5)
```

This code also runs in Python 2.7.  For some reason the first call to `get()` hangs in 3.7, but everything works as expected on other versions.

Comment: Runs as expected for me in Python 3.7.1 - what exactly where you hoping for and how does your 2.7/3.6 output differ from 3.7?

Comment: I'm using 3.7.2.  The goal is to just print from different processes.  It's a toy example of something that does 'real' work in a pool of processes.  As mentioned in the OP, the program completely hangs on the `.get()` call in 3.7.2 so there is no output.  However, in 2.7 or 3.6.8 I see all the prints and the program exits.

Comment: I'm also running in Windows 10, no clue if that matters or not.

Comment: After reading through the Python 3.7 bugs I might be hitting this: https://bugs.python.org/issue35797

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is a regression in Python 3.7.2 as described [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue35797).  It seems to only affect users when running in a virtualenv.

For the time being you can work-around it by doing what's described [in this comment on the bug thread](https://bugs.python.org/msg334163).

```py
import _winapi
import multiprocessing.spawn
multiprocessing.spawn.set_executable(_winapi.GetModuleFileName(0))
```

That will force the subprocesses to spawn using the **real** python.exe instead of the one that's in the virtualenv.  So, this may not be suitable if you're bundling things into an exe with PyInstaller, but it works OK when running from the CLI with local Python installation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip. I wonder if this has been fixed in 3.7.3 so that I can remove this extra work...as I can see a fix has been checked in. See the changelog for `bpo-36010`: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/changelog.html and bug tracker: https://bugs.python.org/issue35797

Comment: FYI, the fix seems to be shipped with 3.7.5rc1 https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/changelog.html