# Problem using Python Multiprocessing Pool.map() becomes Intractable in Python 3.7.2 but completes quickly in 3.6.2

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I just upgraded Python from `3.6.2` -> `3.7.2` and am experiencing an issue with the `multiprocessing` library. I'm using this in a Django Application, which uses a Django-specific function in the worker function (see below.)

In my code I have the following:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from django_app import models

def worker_function(value):
    models.Value.objects.get_or_create(value=value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    list_of_values = [value_1, value_2, ..., value_n]

    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(worker_function, list_of_values)
```

For my application specifically, this task usually runs in ~150-200 seconds.

After upgrading to Python 3.7.2 however, the process hangs indefinitely, though I can attest that my CPU usage spikes considerably.

Switched back to 3.6.2 and everything worked fine again.

I know multiprocessing issues can be complex to diagnose but I'm hoping I just missed a memo somewhere?

NOTE: I have *not* tried this on any other versions of Python than `3.6.2` and `3.7.2`

Update: As a quick means to diagnose, I changed the worker function to simply print the value as such:

```
def worker_function(value):
    print(value)
```

No values were printed during the process(es)

Comment: What's the body of `worker_function` look like?  It's possible that the change is not in multiprocessing, but in something that your worker is doing in the child processes.

Comment: It's a Django function to add create a new model instance, if necessary, using the `Model.objects.get_or_create()` method. See update.

Comment: Same installed versions of Django for both python interpreters (or does it live in a project directory)?  Can you add any logging or exception handling to worker function?  Can you try it with `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` and see if there's any different result (likely slower, but maybe works)?

Comment: Same everything, just updated the core Python version. I tried having the helper function simply print the `str` representation of the value, but it didn't print any—though the CPU usage continued to be quite high on my machine.

Comment: Not saying that is your issue here, but they introduced a regression bug with Python 3.7.2 when used with virtualenv, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54480527/9059420) and the linked bug tracker discussion there.