# Python multiprocessing pool map/starmap does not execute

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Check out the below code. This code executes perfectly on my Mac. When I run the same code on my Windows 10 laptop, it simply does not execute. I am using Pycharm and it shows the file is running but it prints no values nor does it ever finish execution even after *minutes*.

It makes me think there is something wrong with how Python and/or the multiprocessing module is set up on my laptop. I'd appreciate any thoughts here.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def func(x, y):
    print(x, y)
    return x + y

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_list = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]
    p = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()-1)
    output_test = p.starmap(func, test_list)
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

Comment: Can you try this: https://www.python-forum.de/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=44864#p340189

Comment: It's a german forum, but the poster had the same problem as you, and the last piece of code works for him. Maybe if it does for you, too, you can model your attempt based on this.

Comment: @deets Thanks for the prompt suggestion! After google translating everything on that page, I tried the code he claimed to be working but to no avail. The exact issue still persists in which the code never outputs or errors, but simply executes indefinitely.

Comment: Very weird. Sorry I can't be of more help, I'm on the mac myself. So I could only feedback that there was no problem (as you don't see any), and then a solution was suggested and reached.

Comment: Appreciate your help. Downgrading from Python 3.7 -> 3.6 resolves this issue. Seems [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54506728/problem-using-python-multiprocessing-pool-map-becomes-intractable-in-python-3) hours before mine experienced the same issue.