# Pool.imap hangs in venv but works if not using venv

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-venv

I have some problems using multiprocessing and venv in Python 3.7 (in Windows 10). I have the following script in `testing.py`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def square(number):
    return number * number

def main():
    print("Starting")

    p = Pool(1)
    l = [1,2,3]

    for res in p.imap(square, l):
        print("Res:", res)

    print("Done")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And I execute it using the following

```
python testing.py
```

I get the following output (as expected):

```
Starting
Res: 1
Res: 4
Res: 9
Done
```

However, if I create and activate `venv` and then run the same using

```
python -m venv venv
venc\Script\activate.bat
python testing.py
```

The only output i get is

```
Starting
```

and the script never finishes but just keeps waiting. If I deactivate the venv and run it again, then it will work again.

```
venv\Script\deactivate.bin
python testing.py
```

If I, when the script is stuck when i run it in `venv`, press Ctrl+C I get the following:

```
KeyboardInterrupt
Process SpawnPoolWorker-34:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 110, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 351, in get
    with self._rlock:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\synchronize.py", line 95, in __enter__
    return self._semlock.__enter__()
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import context
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import reduction
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 16, in <module>
    import socket
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 963, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 906, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1280, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1252, in _get_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1364, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 81, in _path_stat
```

First time I do it I get `SpawnPoolWorker-1`, second time `SpawnPoolWorker-2` etc, but it just keeps inreasing so it feels like the pool just keep spawning workers, but I do not know why, and why it only does it in `venv`.

Comment: Python 3.7.2 has a regression bug with virtual environments, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54480527/9059420)

Comment: @Darkonaut Thank you for the link, it feels verey much like the same issue.

Comment: Thanks. This was very helpful. @Darkonaut you should add your comment as an answer as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiprocessing AsyncResult.get() hangs in Python 3.7.2 but not in 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54480527/multiprocessing-asyncresult-get-hangs-in-python-3-7-2-but-not-in-3-6)

Comment: @Marius Stănescu It would be better to close this question as duplicate since my answer would only be a link to an already existing answer. I voted for close now.

Comment: @Darkanout I Agree