# python multiprocess not executing function when in virtualenv

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm currently trying to read a giant csv file and want to speed it up via multiprocessing. However, it doesn't even execute the basic test function, neither with apply_async nor map. Nothing happens, with the process not stopping running. This only happens in my virtualenv though.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import csv

def process(rows):
    print(rows)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("mygiganticfile.tsv", encoding='utf-8') as tsvfile:
        tsv_reader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter='\t')
        pool = mp.Pool(4)

        pool.apply_async(process, args=([1, 2, 3],))
        pool.apply_async(process, args=([4, 5, 6],))
        pool.apply_async(process, args=([7, 8, 9],))

        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

im using a standard venv, with python 3.7, this is my pyvenv.cfg:

```
home = C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.7.2
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue, I see the output expected if I run this program. How are you running it?

Comment: im running it in a venv. If I don't do that, it works.

Comment: So your question should be “Why does my code using Python multiprocessing not work in a virtual env when it works not-in-a-virtual-env”?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiprocessing AsyncResult.get() hangs in Python 3.7.2 but not in 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54480527/multiprocessing-asyncresult-get-hangs-in-python-3-7-2-but-not-in-3-6)