# Very basic multiprocessing example with pool.apply() never calls function or terminates

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pool

I am trying to set up the very basic example of `multiprocessing` below. However, the execution only prints `here` and `<_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>` and `pool.apply()` never even calls the function `cube()`. Instead, the execution just keeps running indefinitely without termination.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def cube(x):
    print('in function')
    return x**3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
    print('here')
    print(mp.current_process())

    results = [pool.apply(cube, args=(x,)) for x in range(1,7)]
    print('now here')

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(results)
```

I have tried various other basic examples including `pool.map()` but keep running into the same problem. I am using Python 3.7 on Windows 10. Since I am out of ideas, does anybody know what is wrong here or how I can debug this further?

Thanks!

Comment: Python 3.7.2? Where do you run this (IDE)? Not your problem here, but `pool.apply()` is blocking, even if it would run `cube` it would only be processed sequentially. Switch to `pool.map()` how you already tried.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Python 3.7.2 and my IDE is PyCharm Pro 2019.1. OK, but yeah, `results = pool.map(cube, [1, 2, 3])` leads to the same problem.

Comment: `map()` was a side note, I told you it's not your problem here. With Python 3.7.2 I suspect this regression bug [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54480527/9059420) to be the cause. Should be fixed with Python 3.7.3, I suggest you upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, upgrading to Python 3.7.3 solved the issue.