# Multiprocessing hangs only in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-3.7, python-multiprocessing

I recently tried adding multiprocessing functionality to one of my projects, but I soon discovered that for some reason the call to `Pool.map` was hanging indefinitely.

I tried to make a separate script to test if `Pool.map` would work in a different context:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


def hello(x):
    print(f"Hello there {x}!")


def main():
    p = Pool(5)
    p.map(hello, range(5))
    p.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This also didn't work (nothing would be printed, process was hanging). I then tried to run the above script without activating the virtual environment I had been using so far, and and sure enough, I did get the expected output:

```
Hello there 0!
Hello there 1!
Hello there 2!
Hello there 3!
Hello there 4!
```

The virtual environment was created using `virtualenv .venv`. `virtualenv` was installed using `pip install virtualenv`. I used `python mp_test.py` to run the above script. The `.venv` environment was activated from PowerShell using the `.venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1`.

Comment: Doesn't reproduce on my Linux machine... It's something specific to your environment - OS, Python version, pip version, virtualenv version, Windows version, general computer settings. I'd start trying to change some of these parts to narrow down the culprit.

Comment: "Pool.map was hanging indefinitely." - You surely terminated the script with Ctrl+C ? If so, was there any output ? If so, post it please.

Comment: @OmerTuchfeld it __is__ speciific to at least windows, if not even to the environment of the OP. I cannot reproduce this on Ubuntu with Python3.6

Comment: @dadus can you please post the contents of the Activate.ps1 script ?

Comment: There's a multiprocessing-bug in Python [3.7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54480527/9059420), so make sure you upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: What happens if your `main` is instead: `with Pool(5) as p: p.map(hello, range(5))`? This is equivalent to what you have replacing the call `p.close()` with `p.terminate()`.

Comment: @Darkonaut that seems to be the issue indeed, this is no longer an issue in Python 3.7.9.

Comment: My bad, I forgot the bug _is only_ related to `virtualenv` and the answer in the linked question also mentions it. I use `conda` for environments and skipped 3.7.2 so didn't experience it first hand. This means it's really a dupe.